# What is Windows 2012 default memory page size?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

It appears to be 64kb from analyzing my application's behavior, but I'm looking for a more definitive answer (a link to a reference would be great).

Comment: 64KB? That doesn't sound right at all. Have a read here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2860880#appliesto

Comment: Thanks, but that article is more about the windows page file, not the memory page size.  I'm sure the default page file size is much larger (multiple megabytes).